# Smooth scroll polyfill not working inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling, polyfills

I'm using the smooth scroll polyfill npm package https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll on a website I'm developing and despite trying for hours, I can't get it working. After importing and invoking the package I'm calling a function that adds an event listener to all links with a data attribute of "navigate-to" so that the appropriate element would be scrolled into view. Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing the problem? I suspect it might have something to do with the addeventlistener being appliead inside a forEach? Thanks in advance!

```
    import smoothscroll from "smoothscroll-polyfill";
    smoothscroll.polyfill();

    function anchorScrollTo() {
     document.querySelectorAll("[data-navigateTo]").forEach(function (e) {
     e.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      document.querySelector(e.dataset.navigateto).scrollIntoView({ behaviour: "smooth" });
    });
  });
}
     anchorScrollTo()
```

Comment: A polyfill should only need to be initialised once, your constantly doing inside the loop, this might not be the issue, but it would seem a pointless thing to do.   Also when are you calling anchorScrollTo?,  are you doing after the HTML is rendered?, if you put a `console.log(e)` inside your forEach are you getting the elements?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I accidentally forgot to remove the initialization of the polyfill from the loop, which I added when I was trying to find the issue to see if this could affect the problem. Yes, I'm getting the correct elements when I'm logging them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few more solutions I noticed that the polyfill for some reason does not work with querySelectorAll, so I just created an array of classes that I loop over and select each of the elements with querySelector instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).